# Finding the lenght of the arc KL

Tags: physics

[image]

The beam is sent to the plane mirror which is put on the center of this circular plane and reflected from the point $K$. When the plane mirror is rotated $10°$ in the direction of arrow, the beam is being reflected from the point $L$. Determine the lenght of the arc $KL$.

We need to have that $KL = 10°$.However, when I convert degree to radian, it seems to be $1.74778...$ which is not correct. Therefore, I didn't get how we found $\dfrac{1}{18}$.

**UPDATE:**

the question should be ''How much πr is the lenght of the arc KL?''. Otherwise, it won't make any sense, right? impossible to calculate the lenght without given radius. Thereby, we can try to find it in terms of $\pi r$.

Regards!

Comment: whats the radius of the circle??

Comment: @TheIntegrator That's not given. I think I misread it because we cannot solve this question without knowing the radius. Hence the question should be ''How much $\pi r$ is the lenght of the arc KL''

Comment: Probably , you should recheck whether  you've got the question right.

Comment: @TheIntegrator I've checked it out a sec ago. the question is ''How much $\pi r$ is the lenght of the arc KL''. Otherwise, it won't make any sense right? impossible to calculate the lenght without given radius. Hence we can try finding it in terms of $\pi r$.

Comment: yes it is quiet impossible, in that case $\frac1{18}$ is correct.

Comment: @TheIntegrator Could you explain how you got that answer?

Comment: $\pi^c = 180^\circ\implies  1^\circ = \frac{\pi^c}{180}$. 

Therefore , $10^\circ = 10\cdot\frac{\pi^c}{180} = \frac{\pi^c}{18}$.  So arc length  $l = r\cdot\theta = r\cdot\frac{\pi}{18}$Since it is how many $\pi\cdot r$ the length is the answer is $\frac{1}{18}$

Comment: @TheIntegrator So, is it correct to say that the arc KL is $10^\circ$ ?

Comment: No it is not . It is $10^\circ$ iff $r= 1$ unit.

Comment: @TheIntegrator Therefore, ''Determine the lenght of the arc $KL$'' is wrong, right? It should've been ''How much $πr$ is the lenght of the arc $KL$''

Comment: yes it is wrong

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The KL arc angle is $(50 + 50) - (40 + 40) = 20$ deg

So the arc length is $\frac{1}{9}\pi r$

Comment: The arc lenght is not that.